# How to fix "Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript, optimization

I have minified JS and CSS and optimized images. Used `async="async"` in js where it is applicable. How to fix "Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content"

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `async` and `defer` attributes to your js **params**.

- **async** : load / execute scripts asynchronously.
- **defer** : defer execution at the end of loading the document.

So go to: `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/page.xml`if you haven't it copy it from `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml`

Replace :

`<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>`

With :

`<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script><params>defer</params></action>`

`<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script><params>async</params></action>`

Comment: It's not working, when I added async and defer as per your instruction,stop working all js files and getting  errors.

Comment: We can not resolve this fully in some cases.for more details look this post.https://stackoverflow.com/a/45386507/4373980

Comment: @Yogesh, please tell me how you did fix this issue?